# Parsing SimpleXML Object data

Tags: php, simplexml

How to get "file_url" from this data?

Response can contain few objects, and how to parse it?

Code that I use:

```
<?php
$r34data = simplexml_load_file('https://rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&tags=green_hair&limit=2');
print_r($r34data);
```

Response:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [count] => 69175 [offset] => 0 ) [post] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [height] => 2039 [score] => 1 [file_url] => https://wimg.rule34.xxx/images/3820/01e0a587f6e303c34669a4f79c994100.png [parent_id] => [sample_url] => https://rule34.xxx/samples/3820/sample_01e0a587f6e303c34669a4f79c994100.jpg [sample_width] => 850 [sample_height] => 667 [preview_url] => https://rule34.xxx/thumbnails/3820/thumbnail_01e0a587f6e303c34669a4f79c994100.jpg [rating] => e [tags] => 1boy 2girls annette_(fire_emblem) annette_fantine_dominic ass back back_view bare_back big_ass big_breasts blue_eyes blue_lingerie breasts_outside byleth_(fire_emblem) byleth_(fire_emblem)_(male) byleth_(male) ffm_threesome fingering fingering_partner fire_emblem fire_emblem:_three_houses french_kiss green_hair kissing light_blue_lingerie lingerie long_hair lysithea_(fire_emblem) lysithea_von_ordelia medium_breasts medium_hair nintendo nipples orange_hair pink_eyes purple_lingerie pussy pussy_juice pussy_juice_trail quan_ming sex threesome vaginal_penetration white_hair [id] => 4324333 [width] => 2600 [change] => 1608630074 [md5] => 01e0a587f6e303c34669a4f79c994100 [creator_id] => 503169 [has_children] => false [created_at] => Tue Dec 22 09:21:59 +0000 2020 [status] => active [source] => https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/86455582 [has_notes] => false [has_comments] => false [preview_width] => 150 [preview_height] => 117 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [height] => 1600 [score] => 10 [file_url] => https://wimg.rule34.xxx/images/3820/4a88c87d1cb18928bcee85207bf1c61b.jpeg [parent_id] => [sample_url] => https://rule34.xxx/samples/3820/sample_4a88c87d1cb18928bcee85207bf1c61b.jpg [sample_width] => 850 [sample_height] => 618 [preview_url] => https://rule34.xxx/thumbnails/3820/thumbnail_4a88c87d1cb18928bcee85207bf1c61b.jpg [rating] => e [tags] => 1boy 1boy1girl 1girls all_fours anal anal_sex barefoot bent_over big_breasts christmas clothed_male_nude_female clothing cum cum_in_ass cum_inside cum_leaking doggy_style ejaculation ejaculation_while_penetrated faceless_male feet female female_focus forehead_protector green_hair hair_bun headband huge_breasts kneeling long_hair looking_at_viewer looking_back male multicolored_hair naked naruto naruto_(series) naruto_shippuden nude open_mouth orange_eyes orange_hair pakura penetration pussy santa_costume smile soles standing tied_hair toes two_tone_hair vagina [id] => 4324142 [width] => 2202 [change] => 1608622103 [md5] => 4a88c87d1cb18928bcee85207bf1c61b [creator_id] => 631992 [has_children] => false [created_at] => Tue Dec 22 07:28:01 +0000 2020 [status] => active [source] => [has_notes] => false [has_comments] => false [preview_width] => 150 [preview_height] => 108 ) ) ) )
```

Please help!

(don't ask why I parsing rule34)

Comment: PHP has really quite a good online manual. For SimpleXML, there's [a whole page of usage examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi 
 You can conver it to the array and work with is easy

```php
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$objXmlDocument = simplexml_load_file("https://rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&tags=green_hair&limit=2");

if ($objXmlDocument === FALSE) {
    echo "There were errors parsing the XML file.\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo $error->message;
    }
    exit;
}

$objJsonDocument = json_encode($objXmlDocument);
$arrOutput = json_decode($objJsonDocument, TRUE);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrOutput);
```

Comment: My friend, if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you choose it as the best answer as you wish.

Comment: yes, your answer helped very much, i choosed your answer as best, thanks again (sorry 4 my english, im russian)

Comment: Please don't do that! The SimpleXML object is already designed to give you all the information, and all you're doing by converting it into an array is throwing away information and making life harder for yourself.